# <a href> problem with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse

halo all,

Since I am using nginx reverse proxy for my website.

I reverse proxy sample.com/ (main domain) to sample.com/zh/.

but in sample.com/zh/ page all page  `<a href="about-us">`  will go to sample.com/about-us rather than sample.com/zh/about-us.

Any chance that I can fix this? Thanks all!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another / after the zh so that it's `sample.com/zh/`

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake, I think the url is alredy sample.com/zh/

Comment: Have you tried adding a / in front of about-us? 
Ex: `href="/about-us"`

Comment: I can't change the url in <a href> cause those is too many, and I can't go and change one by one.

Comment: If you're using vscode you can use search and replace (search icon in the left menu bar) to find all the hrefs.